# Tikz-generated PS figure appears very small and upside down with \includegraphics

Tags: tikz-pgf, dvips, ps

I need to use the PS format for every figure in my document.

Under Mac TexShop, I can easily produce Tikz and `pgfplots` PS figures by selecting `Tex + DVI` option under Typesetting and tick the "Save Postscript File" under Engine preferences.

However, when I include them in my document, they remain very small and appear upside down. I have tried to adjust the `width` option from `includegraphics` to make it bigger, but this only makes things worse because the image gets sent out of the page. `trim` and `clip` options just make the image disappear. I also tried modifying the bounding box numbers with the `bb` option from `includegraphics` without any significant result.

Here is the MWE for the main document:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!ht]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[]{kinematics.ps}
\caption{Figure is small and upside down}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

And here is the MWE for producing the "kinematics.ps" file:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{120}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2,tdplot_main_coords]
\draw[thick,-stealth] (0,1.25,0) -- (0,-1,0) node[anchor=south west]{$\mathbf{z}_1$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This is what I get (figure is surrounded by red ellipse):

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: That's weird, indeed. But you can fix the standalone file with `ps2ps kinematics.ps kinematics-a.ps` and include `kinematics-a.ps` in the main document.

Comment: @AlexG This does the trick indeed, it seems to *fix* the original PS file. I wonder however, why can't the original file work as it is...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, the `tikz` option should not be used with `standalone` in file `kinematics.tex`. If, instead, TikZ is loaded as a regular package, the Postscript file `kinematics.ps` is scaled correctly when embedded in the main document.

`kinematics.tex`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{120}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2,tdplot_main_coords]
\draw[thick,-stealth] (0,1.25,0) -- (0,-1,0) node[anchor=south west]{$\mathbf{z}_1$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```